# Phalcon\DI\Injectable not updating services during runtime

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to figure out the logic how Phalcon\Di\Injectable works and I'm a bit confused.

```
class Foo extends \Phalcon\DI\Injectable
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return $this->config->test;
    }
}

$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
$di->set('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'test']);
});
\Phalcon\DI::setDefault($di);

// test 1 : expecting "test"
$bla = new Foo();
$bla->setDI($di);
var_dump($bla->bar());

// test 2 : expecting error "test" undefined
$di->set('config', function() {
    return new \Phalcon\Config();
});
var_dump($bla->bar());

// test 3 : expecting error "test" undefined
$bla2 = new Foo();
$bla2->setDI($di);
var_dump($bla2->bar());
```

The actual output of the script is

```
string(4) "test"
string(4) "test"
string(4) "test"
```

So it seems like once the dependencies have been injected for the first time, they will never get update. The DI container references though the updated object. If you change the method declaration to

```
public function bar()
{
    return $this->di->getConfig()->test;
}
```

it behaves as expected.

The question, is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the logic behind Di\Injectable?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you do can modify objects under `DI()` component, but it may happen tricky.

## 1. Instantiation time

Once you declare object with DI()::set() it may stay uninstantiated until first case of use. As a proof:

```
$di->set('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'test']);
});
$di->set('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'testTwo']);
});
$cnf = $di->get('config'); // get = instantiation
var_dump($cnf);
```

as a result you will get:

```
object(Phalcon\Config)[24]
    public 'test' => string 'testTwo' (length=7)
```

and it will remain this way. With exceptions.

## 2. DI:set() and DI:setShared()

If you would like to have eg. config service configurable during runtime, you should be aware of difference between set() and setShared(). Services created with set() are created all over again with declared anonymous function and its quite difficult to change that. For your example following code snippet:

```
$di->set('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'test']);
});
// context related instance
$cnf = $di->get('config');
$cnf->offsetSet('test', 'testTwo');
var_dump($cnf);

// default instance
$cnf = $di->get('config');
var_dump($cnf);
```

will result in dumping two different results. But once you declare service with setShared(), you will again obtain values dependant on previous actions on object:

```
$di->setShared('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'test']);
});
$cnf = $di->get('config');
$cnf->offsetSet('test', 'testTwo');
var_dump($cnf);

$cnf = $di->get('config');
var_dump($cnf);
```

because service is not reinstantiated. If you ever found you willing to replace DI() service with other one, you have to take your time and find proper DI() (because services may have their exclusive dependency list) to do that, but its possible:

```
$di->set('config',  function () use ($di) {
    return new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'testError']);
});
$cnf = $di->get('config');
var_dump($cnf);

$di->set('config', new \Phalcon\Config(['test' => 'testProper']));
$cnf = $di->get('config');
var_dump($cnf);
```

Got it working with setShared() too. And result as a proof:

```
object(Phalcon\Config)[25]
  public 'test' => string 'testError' (length=9)
object(Phalcon\Config)[26]
  public 'test' => string 'testProper' (length=10)
```

Hope it's claryfying some things. Useful link: [Dependency Injection manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/di.html).

Provided with Phalcon 1.3.2.

## 3 Edit - reinstantiation:

Your example between test1 and test2 is working as expected. Once you use `$this->config` it is being instantiated with declared closure, and kept that way. But you do can obtain behavior you want by modyfying a bit your bar() function:

```
public function bar()
{
    $di = $this->getDI();
    return $di->get('config')->test;
}
```

this way, as it is ambiguous if object has been instantiated in Foo context only, or not, Phalcon will produce new Object based on your closure in DI::set(). And this will throw your expected 'undefined' error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yergo. But that's not really what I'm having problem with. The DI container (or **Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault**) behaves as expected. I'm able to update services during runtime without any problems. And your examples show that also. The problematic is the  **Phalcon\Di\Injectable** which is not handling updates to services.

Comment: Added third part to my answer. Sorry I missed that on the first time ;) Hopes im helpful ;)

Comment: One of the benefits of the DI is the ease of redefining the services during runtime for the sake of injecting mocks and stubs for unit testing. And it's not possible with the **Di\Injectable**. If I always need to resolve up-to-date dependencies though the DI container, why do I have to extend the **Di\Injectable**? So what's the purpose of it? And third case in my example looks like a proper bug, because I'm explicitly passing update DI container to new instance.